# Raspberry pi locking mechanism is insecure by default

Tags: security, user

I've followed a tutorial that lets me lock my Raspberry pi. Though I do not know which one it was I assume it was [this](https://thepihut.com/blogs/raspberry-pi-tutorials/how-to-lock-your-raspberry-pi-screen) one.

However when I lock it I could just press Crtl+Alt+F7 to get right back into it. Now a normal person who doesn't use computers would (likely) never find about this unless I told them or something. But this leaves my Raspberry pi very insecure.

And what makes matters slightly worse: Is that if I have 2 users I can easily switch to and from their and my account by pressing Ctrl+Alt+F(N)

Also I accidentally found this shortcut out by myself a few years back so it's easy, really to hack into a pi with this configuration and this knowledge

Bottom line:

---

How can I make it so that they can't use that keyboard shortcut to get *right back into my* Raspberry pi?

Comment: Configure a login with password and logout.

Comment: *"so it's easy, really to hack into a pi with this configuration and this knowledge"* -> I think it's commonly said WRT security that you cannot  prevent someone with physical access to a machine from hacking into it in this sense, presuming the machine is a normal computer and not an ATM.

Comment: *"if I have 2 users I can easily switch to and from their and my account by pressing Ctrl+Alt+F(N)"* -> I usually think of this as a feature since the two users are pretty much always me, lol.  However, you're right, it is a bit lame.  Do you normally use a password login? There should be a way to configure the display manager to do this.   Pretty sure that's `lightdm` and part responsible for this is called *light locker*, which looks to be optional and so may not actually be installed: https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=light-locker

Comment: Also of the people I'm concerned about hacking in to my Raspberry PI are less than 16 and most of them don't have any knowledge of hacking anything. They're not going to think of looking it up either. I just don't want them tinkering around and getting on my Raspberry Pi. 

Yes I normally use a password to login from the gui.

Comment: And once they know that key combo there's no stopping them from getting on my Raspberry Pi if it is locked not logged out that is. So as a temporary fix I'd just log out every time I don't want some one getting on it.

Comment: No, it is installed: 
`whereis lightdm
lightdm: /usr/sbin/lightdm /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/lightdm /etc/lightdm /usr/share/lightdm /usr/share/man/man1/lightdm.1.gz`